# Could not write JSON: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher

Tags: java, encryption, des, jce

I have followed a guide to simply encrypt and decrypt a string but I can't somehow make it work

I want to have a constant key so I don't need to save it to my database and waste space

I just want to encrypt some personal data not password

do you guys have any idea?

I'm following [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jce-encryption-data-encryption-standard-des-tutorial/) guide please it

```
      public String getAction() throws Exception {
            String encodedKey = "eightkey";
            byte[] key = encodedKey.getBytes();
            decodedKey.length, "DES");

            SecretKey myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");
            Cipher desCipher;
            desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
            byte[] text = action.getBytes();
            byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
            String getAct = ""+textEncrypted;

                return getAct;
        }

        public void setAction(String action) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

            String encodedKey = "eightkey";
            byte[] key = encodedKey.getBytes();
            SecretKey myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");
            Cipher desCipher;
            desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            byte[] text = action.getBytes();
            desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
            byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
            String setAct = ""+textEncrypted;
            this.action = setAct;
        }
```

Full error here

```
2018-04-12 17:06:34.587  WARN 1572 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher (through reference chain: com.capstone.codegum.Codegum.Objects.Logs["action"])
```

Comment: you should not convert it to string using `"" + byte[]`. Base64 encode that `byte[]`

Comment: **Do not use DES for new work**, it is no longer considered secure and has been superceeded by AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) and is no more difficult to use. DES only has key size is only 56 bits which is not considered to be secure, AES supports key sizes of 128,192 and 256 bits. See [Security comparison of DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181/5121).

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit and able to run it. Here is a running example:

Pojo.java

```
package com.test;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Pojo {
    private byte[] action = null;
    private SecretKey myDesKey = null;
    private String encodedKey = "eightkey";

    public String getAction() throws Exception {
        Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

        byte[] text = action;
        byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
        String getAct = new String(textEncrypted);

        return getAct;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) throws Exception {
        Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] key = encodedKey.getBytes();
        this.myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");
        desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

        byte[] text = action.getBytes();
        byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
        this.action = textEncrypted;
    }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
package com.test;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pojo p = new Pojo();
        p.setAction("hello");
        String s = p.getAction();
        System.out.println(s);
        p.setAction("world");
        s = p.getAction();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

Answer (score 0):

Use byte[] actionBytes instead of String action something of the sort:

```
private byte[] actionBytes;

public String getAction() throws Exception {

    String encodedKey = "eightkey";
    byte[] key = encodedKey.getBytes("UTF8");
    SecretKey myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");

    Cipher desCipher;
    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);      
    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(actionBytes);
    return new String(textEncrypted);
}

public void setAction(String action) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String encodedKey = "eightkey";
    byte[] key = encodedKey.getBytes("UTF8");       

    SecretKey myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");

    Cipher desCipher;
    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] text = action.getBytes("UTF8");
    desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
    actionBytes = textEncrypted;
}
```

Or if you want to keep using String action then you should do this:

```
public String action;

public String getAction() throws Exception {

    String encodedKey = "eightkey";
    byte[] key = encodedKey.getBytes("UTF8");
    SecretKey myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");

    Cipher desCipher;
    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);      
    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(action.getBytes("UTF8"));
    return new String(textEncrypted);
}

public void setAction(String action) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    String encodedKey = "eightkey";
    byte[] key = encodedKey.getBytes("UTF8");       

    SecretKey myDesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DES");

    Cipher desCipher;
    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] text = action.getBytes("UTF8");
    desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
    action = new String(textEncrypted, "UTF8");
}
```

Comment: Basically the problem is the encrypted string that you are creating needs to be created with UTF8 encoding. byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(action.getBytes("UTF8"));